# Enable disable the fields/controls in React Kendo Grid

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

I want to disable the fields/controls in React kendo grid based on input.

For example : Based on selection of value in **Full Name**, I want to disable the **Birth Date** column 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the [desired behavior by using a Custom Editor](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-custom/). The `Custom Editor` receives the entire dataItem and is re-rendered on each change of the dateItem fields.

So you could create a custom `DatePickerCell` and set the DatePicker `disabled` prop based on the value of the FullName. Also set the `cell` prop of the BirthDate `GridColumn` to `DatePickerCell`.

```
class DatePickerCell extends React.Component {
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.props.onChange({
            dataItem: this.props.dataItem,
            field: this.props.field,
            syntheticEvent: e.syntheticEvent,
            value: e.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        const dataValue = this.props.dataItem[this.props.field];

        if (!this.props.dataItem.inEdit) {
            return (
                <td>
                    {this.props.dataItem[this.props.field].toDateString()}
                </td>
            );
        }

        return (
            <td>
                <DatePicker
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={dataValue}
                    disabled={this.props.dataItem['FullName'] === 'Bradshow, John'}
                />
            </td>
        );
    }
}

<GridColumn field="BirthDate" title="Birth Date" editor="date" format="{0:d}" cell={DatePickerCell} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. is there any way to reflect the value in other control based on dropdown selection change? For example if I select the full name from dropdown I want to populate lastname , firstname in the same row of grid

Comment: Yes, you could create CustomEditors wrapping Input for the firstname and lastname. Then inside the render method of the CustomEditor, set the value of the Input based on this.props.dataItem['FullName'].